# What does this Solidity notation mean: (uint256 rAmount,,,,,)

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I'm looking through the SAFEMOON contract here: https://bscscan.com/address/0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3#code

On line 835, the following notation is used:

```
(uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);
```

I'm wondering what the additional commas after `rAmount` mean.
My intention is to understand this code so I can understand the smart contract.
Any help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a look at the function signature of that function, it's `function _getValues(uint256 tAmount) private view returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256)`. It returns 6 values, so you could get the return values with something like `(uint256 a, b, c, d, e, f) = _getValues(tAmount);`.

If, however, you are not interested in all of the return values, you can simply assign them to "empty" slot. So if you only want to assign the first return variable, and not assign the rest of the return values anywhere, you can use `(uint256 rAmount,,,,,) = _getValues(tAmount);`